# I can't see data I have added using forms on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am using php and mysql to add data to a database. When I add data to a form and submit the data I get a message saying the data has been successfully added. However when I view the database on phpmyadmin all I see is a blank row with nothing but the primary key. The database is storing cricket players that the user has entered.
UPDATE: I put the colons in just like everyone said and now the IF statement comes back saying Could not add data. So now it is not adding anything at all.
Here is my code:

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$teamrole=$_POST['teamrole'];
$testruns=$_POST['testruns'];
$testwickets=$_POST['testwickets'];
$odiruns=$_POST['odiruns'];
$odiwickets=$_POST['odiwickets'];
$truns=$_POST['truns'];
$twickets=$_POST['twickets'];
$searchteam=$_POST['searchteam'];

$query="INSERT INTO player VALUES (NULL, :First_Name, :Last_Name, :Date_of_Birth, :Team_Role, :Test_Runs, :Test_Wickets, :ODI_Runs, :ODI_Wickets, :t20_Runs, :t20_Wickets, :TeamID) ";

$stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':First_Name', $fname);
$stmt->bindValue(':Last_Name', $lname);
$stmt->bindValue(':Date_Of_Birth', $dob);
$stmt->bindValue(':Team_Role', $teamrole);
$stmt->bindValue(':Test_Runs', $testruns);
$stmt->bindValue(':Test_Wickets', $testwickets);
$stmt->bindValue(':ODI_Runs', $odiruns);
$stmt->bindValue(':ODI_Wickets', $odiwickets);
$stmt->bindValue(':t20_Runs', $truns);
$stmt->bindValue(':t20_Wickets', $twickets);
$stmt->bindValue(':TeamID', $searchteam);
$affected_rows = $stmt->execute();
if($affected_rows==1)
{
    echo "Successfully added the details for ".$fname;
}
else
{
    echo "Could not add data for ".$fname;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `:` in the query as well?

Comment: You don't have the playerID binded anywhere

Comment: Don't edit the content out of your questions, leave it there so future visitors can see the problem and hopefully get help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't quite correctly constructed, you'll need to add the parameters using `:`, something like this;

```
$query="INSERT INTO `player` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Date_of_Birth`, 
           `Team_Role`, `Test_Runs`, `Test_Wickets`, `ODI_Runs`, `ODI_Wickets`,
           `t20_Runs`, `t20_Wickets`, `TeamID`)
           VALUES (:First_Name, :Last_Name, :Date_of_Birth, :Team_Role, 
                   :Test_Runs, :Test_Wickets, :ODI_Runs, :ODI_Wickets,
                   :t20_Runs, :t20_Wickets, :TeamID)";
```

Note that since it's automatically generated you should leave out the value for the PlayerID primary key, which you can only do if you're listing the columns where you actually want to insert values.

As a secondary benefit, if you ever decide to add a field to your table, listing the fields involved in the query like this will prevent the insert from failing because of missing columns.

Comment: I put the colons in and now it saying that I can not add data

Comment: @user2970528 Does it give a more specific error message than that? Also, are you using this insert or just your original one with added colons?

Comment: No it doesn't give me any error message. It just gives me back the echo I have in the IF statement if it fails to add data. I used the original one with added colons. Do I have to copy exactly what you have typed?

Comment: @user2970528 Try this one copied "as is", just adding colons to your original query will probably fail since you've not bound a value to PlayerID but still have it mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Your binding names are wrong in your query - remove the ` characters and use semi colons (as per your binding variables). Also, when you're inserting a new row, you don't specify the primary key as it should be generated automatically.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `player` VALUES (null, :First_Name, :Last_Name, :Date_of_Birth, :Team_Role, :Test_Runs, :Test_Wickets, :ODI_Runs, :ODI_Wickets, :t20_Runs, :t20_Wickets, :TeamID) ";
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I put the colons in and now its saying that I can not add data

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is incorrect.  You're binding on parameters that start with colons, but your sql statement doesn't include them

```
$query="INSERT INTO `player` VALUES (NULL, :First_Name, :Last_Name ...
```

Back ticks are also MySQL's field delimiters.

Comment: I put the colons in and now it saying that I can not add data

Comment: Most likely because you're not binding to PlayerID.  What is the exact error generated by the query.  Look into errorInfo for PDO: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: strange thing is I am not even getting an error, my IF statement is coming back as saying no data could be added

Comment: Change your else statement to `echo "Could not add data for ".$fname . " - " . print_r($stmt->errorInfo(),true);`

Comment: My query wasn't constructed clearly. But the code you gave me helped me a lot too. Thanks!